# How to unittest validation of arguments in argparse using assertRaises() in Python?

Tags: python, exception, argparse, python-unittest

When trying to Unittest validations of arguments in argparse the following works:

mymodule:

```
def validate_mac_addr(mac_addr):
    regex = re.compile(r'^((([a-f0-9]{2}:){5})|(([a-f0-9]{2}-){5}))[a-f0-9]{2}$', re.IGNORECASE)

    if re.match(regex, mac_addr) is not None:
        return mac_addr
    msg = f"[-] Invalid MAC address: '{mac_addr}'"
    raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
```

test:

```
import mymodule
import unittest

  def test_mac_address_false(self):
            self.assertRaises(Exception, mymodule.validate_mac_addr,"n0:ma:ca:dd:re:ss:here")
```

But I wanted to catch a the more specific 'ArgumentTypeError' but this is apparently not possible with arssertRaises() in this example!? What is going on with the general usage of Exception in assertRaises()?

BTW

```
isinstance(argparse.ArgumentTypeError, Exception)
```

Returns False?!

Ref.: [class ArgumentTypeError(Exception):](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Lib/argparse.py#l725)

Answer (score 0):

`argparse.ArgumentTypeError` is a *subclass*, not an instance, of `Exception`, and is the type of exception you should be asserting gets raised.

```
import argparse


def test_mac_address_false(self):
    self.assertRaises(argparse.ArgumentTypeError, mymodule.validate_mac_addr, "n0:ma:ca:dd:re:ss:here")
```

Comment: You answer cleared things up for me. Thank you. Now the test also passes with argparse.ArgumentTypeError. I was getting "NameError: name 'argparse' is not defined". I forgot to import argparse in the unittest file.